# Template with sized return type in function C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variables, storage

Is it possible to design a template function in such a way

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T3 f(T1 x, T2 y);
```

where if `sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)` then `T3 = T1`, otherwise `T3 = T2`

Further request...

I tried to define something like:

```
template <int i>
struct A {
    int a;
};

template <int j>
struct B {
    int b;
};

template <int i, int j>
typename std::conditional< i > j , A<i>, B<j> >::type
func() {
    ;
}
```

But when i try to compile ...

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o main.o "..\\main.cc" 
In file included from ..\main.cc:8:0:
..\header.h:34:30: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
 typename std::conditional< i > j , A<i>, B<j> >::type
                              ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\move.h:57:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:59,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from ..\header.h:11,
                 from ..\main.cc:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\type_traits:77:12: error: provided for 'template<bool <anonymous>, class, class> struct std::conditional'
     struct conditional;
            ^
In file included from ..\main.cc:8:0:
..\header.h:34:32: error: 'j' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 typename std::conditional< i > j , A<i>, B<j> >::type
                                ^
..\header.h:34:34: error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
 typename std::conditional< i > j , A<i>, B<j> >::type
```

So basically doesn't work in that case... (non type templates).

Comment: Such an `f` looks like it might be related to arithmetics. If it is, you might also be interested in [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type).

Comment: Your new issue is that you need to put parentheses round `i > j`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `std::conditional`:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::conditional< (sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)),
                  T1, T2 >::type
f(T1 x, T2 y);
```

If you wanted, you could factor this out like so:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using largest_type = 
    typename std::conditional< (sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)),
                               T1, T2 >::type;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
largest_type<T1,T2>
f(T1 x, T2 y);
```

Writing `largest_type` as a variadic template is left as an exercise :D

Comment: `std::conditional_t< bla >` in c++14

Comment: `template<bool b, class T0, class T1> conditional_t = typename std::conditional<b,T0,T1>::type;` in C++11.  Friends don't let friends spam their code with `typename`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a vexing parse!

```
typename std::conditional< i > j , A<i>, B<j> >::type
//                           ^
//                           Looks like the close of template params
```

Put parens around the expression:

```
typename std::conditional< (i > j) , A<i>, B<j> >::type
```

or reverse the condition:

```
typename std::conditional< j < i , A<i>, B<j> >::type
```

Comment: I apparently solved, but i would like to develop a more complex case to present into this thread, so before to choice an answer i will develop such case.